# Async task returning data after ORMLite database has been closed from screen rotation

Tags: android, android-asynctask, ormlite, screen-rotation

I receive this error

```
10-11 13:58:46.713: E/AndroidRuntime(29407): FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #2
10-11 13:58:46.713: E/AndroidRuntime(29407): java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
10-11 13:58:46.713: E/AndroidRuntime(29407):    at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:299)
10-11 13:58:46.713: E/AndroidRuntime(29407):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerSetException(FutureTask.java:273)
10-11 13:58:46.713: E/AndroidRuntime(29407):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:124)
10-11 13:58:46.713: E/AndroidRuntime(29407):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:307)
10-11 13:58:46.713: E/AndroidRuntime(29407):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:137)
10-11 13:58:46.713: E/AndroidRuntime(29407):    at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:230)
10-11 13:58:46.713: E/AndroidRuntime(29407):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1076)
10-11 13:58:46.713: E/AndroidRuntime(29407):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:569)
10-11 13:58:46.713: E/AndroidRuntime(29407):    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
10-11 13:58:46.713: E/AndroidRuntime(29407): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: attempt to re-open an already-closed object: SQLiteDatabase: /data/data/com.philly.philly/databases/PhillyORM.db
10-11 13:58:46.713: E/AndroidRuntime(29407):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteClosable.acquireReference(SQLiteClosable.java:55)
10-11 13:58:46.713: E/AndroidRuntime(29407):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.rawQueryWithFactory(SQLiteDatabase.java:1310)
10-11 13:58:46.713: E/AndroidRuntime(29407):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.rawQuery(SQLiteDatabase.java:1253)
10-11 13:58:46.713: E/AndroidRuntime(29407):    at com.j256.ormlite.android.AndroidCompiledStatement.getCursor(AndroidCompiledStatement.java:154)
10-11 13:58:46.713: E/AndroidRuntime(29407):    at com.j256.ormlite.android.AndroidCompiledStatement.runQuery(AndroidCompiledStatement.java:57)
10-11 13:58:46.713: E/AndroidRuntime(29407):    at com.j256.ormlite.stmt.SelectIterator.<init>(SelectIterator.java:55)
10-11 13:58:46.713: E/AndroidRuntime(29407):    at com.j256.ormlite.stmt.StatementExecutor.buildIterator(StatementExecutor.java:206)
10-11 13:58:46.713: E/AndroidRuntime(29407):    at com.j256.ormlite.stmt.StatementExecutor.query(StatementExecutor.java:155)
10-11 13:58:46.713: E/AndroidRuntime(29407):    at com.j256.ormlite.dao.BaseDaoImpl.query(BaseDaoImpl.java:261)
10-11 13:58:46.713: E/AndroidRuntime(29407):    at com.j256.ormlite.stmt.QueryBuilder.query(QueryBuilder.java:262)
10-11 13:58:46.713: E/AndroidRuntime(29407):    at com.j256.ormlite.stmt.Where.query(Where.java:482)
10-11 13:58:46.713: E/AndroidRuntime(29407):    at com.j256.ormlite.dao.BaseDaoImpl.queryForEq(BaseDaoImpl.java:241)
10-11 13:58:46.713: E/AndroidRuntime(29407):    at com.philly.philly.Repository.saveOrUpdateKontext(Repository.java:180)
10-11 13:58:46.713: E/AndroidRuntime(29407):    at com.philly.philly.PostListActivity$LoadPostsTask.doInBackground(PostListActivity.java:161)
10-11 13:58:46.713: E/AndroidRuntime(29407):    at com.philly.philly.PostListActivity$LoadPostsTask.doInBackground(PostListActivity.java:1)
10-11 13:58:46.713: E/AndroidRuntime(29407):    at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
10-11 13:58:46.713: E/AndroidRuntime(29407):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:305)
10-11 13:58:46.713: E/AndroidRuntime(29407):    ... 5 more
```

I believe the key part being `10-11 13:58:46.713: E/AndroidRuntime(29407): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: attempt to re-open an already-closed object: SQLiteDatabase: /data/data/com.philly.philly/databases/PhillyORM.db`

This occurs when I rotate my screen while an async task is retrieving data from the remote server.

What I am assuming is happening is that the request is coming back and attempting to write to the database but the activity which started the task has been destroyed and restarted.

If you need to see my code I will add it but I thought the source of this problem might actually be pretty clear just from the error messages and my description.

I'm just looking for how to properly handle screen rotations when retrieving remote data and writing to a local database using ORMLite. Maybe I should be using a service instead of async task?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Your activity is probably closing the DB on rotation.
My suggestion is to use an AsyncTaskLoader and it will take care of the rotation by itself. http://developer.android.com/guide/components/loaders.html

Also a tip I've learned from experience is to have a singleton DB object that will only be opened once through the whole life of your application... and when the application dies, the object is closed automatically.

Comment: Ok, i'll give this a spin. Thanks. also, i will report back. :)

Answer (score 0):

You are better off using a service to take care of database. When you rotate the screen current layout with all components is destroyed and new one is build using new orientation layout (which will have other components). Also you have the option to block the rotation of screen if you don't really use it.